# How to limit the Axis range on Performance Point Analytic Chart?

Tags: charts, performancepoint

I have an Analytic Grid created in Dashboard Designer for SharePoint 2010 that displays some measures in percentage. The range of the series starts from 0% to 100%. I want to have the range start from 60% to 100%. Is this possible in Dashboard Designer. If possible, help please.

[image: Limit the Axis range on Performance Point Analytic Chart]

Thanks,
Merin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. You need to use tools like SSRS or Excel to get more control of chart behavior.